# Get today's date in Apache pig job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I want to use today's date in the output files path in one of my pig jobs which is suppose to run daily, Is there a way to do that. 
Something like 
`/user/x/$todaysDate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this via bash:

```
echo '/user/x/'`date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

gives:

```
/user/x/2012-10-14
```

---

So, you would execute your script as:

```
$ pig -param outpath='/user/x/'`date +%Y-%m-%d` myscript.pig
```

Then, in your `STORE` command, use `$outpath`:

```
STORE abc INTO '$outpath';
```